# SQL SSRS Remove Blank Space after hiding a column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report that consists of a simple data dump tablix.

Here is what my tablix looks like.

[image]

I am giving the user an option on what to group by, using a parameter, with their option being None, Master Code, and Sub Code.

I am following this tutorial

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dynamic-grouping-in-ssrs-reports

So as you can see, all the way to the left, I have a column called Group Desc which tells the user what the data is being grouped by, if it is being grouped.

Except in there, the Group header is a row, while mine is a column. 
I wrote the expression to hide the column, and it works, but it leaves a huge blank space where the column was.

So when selecting something to group by, it works perfectly. However, when selecting the option none, to indicate I don't want to group by anything, it hides that column like specified in the expression, but leaves a blank space where it was.

[image]

I need a way to hide the column and remove the blank space that it fills. Is that possible in SSRS?

Comment: Roundabout way, but create another tablix without the group by and toggle each tablix based on the same expression to hide the column.

Comment: I understand. However, if I have two tablix stacked upon each other, then when I need to see the bottom one (lets assume that is the one without grouping) won't there be a big space before it (where the top one was) ?